# Scan multicast IP range on specific port using nmap

Tags: nmap

I'd like to scan a multicast IP range on a specific port using nmap.

When I try to simply do a nmap -p 10000 239.35.0.0/16, it just responds with an error stating Strange error from connect (47):Address family not supported by protocol family

Is it even possible to scan multicast using nmap, or what am I doing wrong?

PS: For those wondering: "Why the hell does he want to scan an entire /16 ?":

I'm trying to list all active IPTV servers on the network of ISP (Deutsche Telekom) to see which ones are accessible using VLC.

Thanks

Tobias

Comment: You shouldn't really be scanning your ISP's network. It could get you in some serious trouble.

Answer (score 2):

If you asking if nMap can scan networks based on a mask then,  yes it can do so.

The details have been given here:
http://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html

As for the error you are getting. Some quick web searches and previous programming in Python indicates a driver error, which may be resulting from a glitch wherein nMap can resolve the hosts IP for an undermined reason.

If getting the job done is priority try an alternative approach.

1. Use a mask converter or maths to get the range of IPs to scan.
   http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=239.35.0.0&mask1=16&mask2=
2. Then, issue this command in nmap. `nmap 239.35.0.0-239.35.255.254`

*Note: Neither StackExchange or I promote unauthorized illegal port scan of networks. This answer is merely to inform you about the capabilities of nMap.*